# Rim lighting setup

Tags: light, edges

I want to get effect of rim lighting, similar to this picture:[image]

I found some photography tips which I tried to use but all i got is:[image]

Can someone help me with proper lighting setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give your object a material with a setup like this. The key is the Fresnel Node. I made the world background pure black, and placed a large (proportionally), and bright area light behind the object at a direct (90 degree) angle.

[image: RimLight]

Here is the lighting setup - just a big area light:

[image: LightSetup]

Comment: Looks a lot better :) thank you

Answer (score 5):

To get similar results, you need two things:

1. Increase geometry resolution with Subdivision Modifier
2. Shade Smooth your model, to get continuous shading areas

*(Keep in mind, the referenced photo was also heavily processed)*

[image][image]

The exact lighting is a matter of preference, yours (top/bottom) works just as well.

[image]

Comment: I focused so hard on lighting, so I forgot about the most basic thing...