# Rim lighting / Silhouette

Tags: lighting

[image: Rim lit spheres – sorry, source unknown (via Designinspiration.com)]

I'm a bit of a novice so please bear with me. I'm trying to create this effect. Is this just done with rim lighting? and if so, what do people recomend as the bset setup for this sort of thing?

The object I'm trying to light is a horseshoe, but I'm not having much luck achieving those lovely soft shadows (frsnel?). I followed the suggestions by Jachym Michal here: [Rim lighting setup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187793/rim-lighting-setup) but my highlights are very harsh and I could only achieve the effect by rotating on the Z axis slightly, would this be because the objust doesn't have much in the way of profile for the light to catch? If so, does anyone have any tips to change this?

Thanks for any suggestions

[image]

Comment: It looks rather good, if your object has sharp edges it seems normal that you don't get the same result as a smooth objects like a sphere